# How to generate code from ecore model with OCL expressions in the separate file?

Tags: ocl, ecore

I'm using Eclipse addon to work with OCL. I have an Ecore model with some operations and derived attributes also I have a separate OCL file with expressions in it. I made a genmodel file and added:

```
<genAnnotations source="http://www.eclipse.org/OCL/GenModel">
    <details key="Use Delegates" value="false"/>
</genAnnotations>
```

Also I checked that in the preferences realisation of OCL embedded within ecore models set to generate code. But when I try to generate code using this genmodel it only generates code without OCL expressions in it. What else should I do to generate code for all OCL expressions from a separate file?

Here is my model file: [ecore file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPP2h.png)

Here is my genmodel file:[.genmodel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfI73.png)

Start of OCL file:

```
import 'CarRental.ecore#/'

package CarRental

context Person
inv Person3:
  age > 0 and age < 80

context Person::fullName : String
  derive: self.firstname.concat(' ').concat(self.lastname)
...
endpackage
```

Model file in OCLinEcore:

```
package CarRental : CarRental = 'http:///CarRental.ecore'
{
    class Person
    {
        operation email() : String[*|1];
        operation updateAge(newAge : ecore::EInt[1]);
        attribute firstname : String[?];
        attribute lastname : String[?];
        attribute age : ecore::EInt[1];
        attribute isMarried : Boolean[1];
        attribute fullName : String[?] { derived };
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An outright Eclipse question should be asked on the Eclipse OCL newsgroup.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/26/

Your Ecore/GenModel files are not Ecore/GenModel files; they are snapshots of the top level declarations. snapshots are very rarely good substitutes for files.

Your genmodel snippet looks good, but without the rest of the project it is very difficult to comment on the many possible mistakes you could have made.

My best guess is that given that you post a Sample Ecore Model Editor snapshot rather than an OCLinEcore editor snapshot, you have failed to synthesize all the EAnnotations that are necessary to register your OCL add-ons. The OCLinEcore editor does it all automatically.

I suggest you post a zipped project to the Eclipse OCL newsgroup.

Comment: Ok, I have failed to synthesize EAnnotations because in OCLinEcore there is no notations at all. How exactly can I synthesize them automatically or manually?

Comment: If you edit your Ecore file using the OCLinEcore editor it should just happen.

Answer (score 0):

Once details were provided on the Eclipse OCL Forum, it transpired that there were no OCLExpressions from which to generate code. Zero in => zero out.